# Calculating degrees for bouncing ball

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a simple breakout game and I have some problem how to calculate the angle when the ball hit the top border. When the ball moves upwards in an angle of 180 degrees, then it bouncing back downwards in an angle of 0 degrees. But when the ball is moving upwards in an angle of 170 degrees, then it should be bouncing back downwards in a mirrored angle, like 10 degrees. I can calculate this like `180-170 = 10` degrees, but what if the ball is moving upwards in an angle of 190 degrees!? Then it should be bouncing back downwards in an angle of 350 degrees, but I don't know how to calculate this!?

Is there a simple way to calculate or mirror the value of the upwards moving angle of the ball? Preciate some help because I'm not good in math! Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm moving the ball like this:

```
xPos += speed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(direction));
yPos += speed * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(direction));
```

Comment: Just negate the values of x and y when they reach the walls..no need to calculate the degrees check this it might be helpful http://learnersdirectory.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-brick-game-tutorial.html

Comment: Does that really works!? I read the code, but I can't find where the negate thing happens!? Could you make an answer to my question with an example?

Comment: if(x>gameview.getWidth()-width-speedx || x+speedx<0)
        {
            speedx=-speedx;
        }
        if(y>gameview.getHeight()-height-speedy || y+speedy<0)
        {
            speedy=-speedy;
        }

Comment: I have provided the complete application project there if you wish download it and check it  http://www.ziddu.com/download/20790460/brickgame.zip.html

Comment: OK, but if you negate a value, isn't the ball moving back in the same angle then?

Comment: I will suggest you to follow this tutorial is it helped me a lot in understanding mirroring and moving sprites and animations etc, Best tutorial for beginners http://www.edu4java.com/androidgame.html  , This will explain you how that happens

Comment: OK! Good link! Thanks!

Comment: Why not you just apply 360 degree to calculation if it's smaller than 0? This is default behavior i guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question regarding angles and reflection:

1. Decide on your system of angle measurement. You told that a ball that is moving upwards is at an angle of `180°`, so I guess `0°` is pointing downwards and the angle is increasing in counter-clockwise direction (`90°` points to the right etc.). It is important to be consistent. Let `d` be the angle of the ball's movement in that system.
2. Define the angle of the normal vector of your border. If the border at the top is horizontal, its normal vector is perpendicular to it and has an angle of `0°` (in the measurement system defined in point 1). Let `n` be that angle. A vertical border would have `n = 90°`.
3. The outgoing angle `o` of the ball is given by:

   `o = 2*n - d - 180°`

   Note that you might have to normalize this angle i.e. you add/subtract `360°` to/from o until `0° <= o < 360°`.

Your example with `d = 190°, n = 0°`:

```
o = 2*0° - 190° - 180° = -370°
```

This will result in `o = 350°` after normalization, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. When ball bounces of horizontal surface just change sign of it vertical speed. And when it hit vertical wall change sign of vertical speed. I hope that you have speed and coordinates as 2D vectors (pair of horizontal and vertical components), like x,y as ball coordinates and vX, vY as ball speed.

And maybe it's a good idea that when ball hits the brick move it one step back, right before the hit and then do speed component sign inversion.